# How to join the 8 table in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Hi  i have nearly 8 table where i need to join and get the complete result .Please any help me regarding this .I have doubt that can we use instead of joins.

Comment: nearly 8 tables? so... like seven tables? or seven tables and a view ?

Comment: Why would you doubt it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 8 tables named:

```
a having id and data1 attributes.
b having id and data2 attributes.
c having id and data3 attributes.
d having id and data4 attributes.
e having id and data5 attributes.
f having id and data6 attributes.
g having id and data7 attributes.
h having id and data8 attributes.
```

Then, if you want to show the data of all the tables:

```
sql>select a.data1,b.data2,c.data3,d.data4,e.data5,f.data6,g.data7,h.data8 from a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h where a.id=b.id and b.id=c.id and c.id=d.id and d.id=e.id and e.id=f.id and f.id=g.id and g.id=h.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* join eight tables, there's nothing in the SQL spec that forbids it and I'd be very surprised if a decent DBMS was limited to that level. And yes, despite its inability to tell the difference between an empty string and a NULL, many *do* consider Oracle decent :-)

However, I would suggest that you post your schema and  which columns you need here so we can help you out from a higher level.

Even in enterprise databases, it's relatively rare to see a complex join like that. There's also the possibility of performance issues for such a query.

Comment: I consider Oracle decent *because* it does away with trying to make an unnatural distinction between empty and NULL. ;-)

Comment: Oooh, @Thilo, I'm _so_ tempted to start a religious war on the need to distinguish between known-and-blank and unknown but I'll refrain :-) Mostly because of the winkie.

Answer (score -1):

a join over that many tables is quite possible, but can get hard to read.
It might be better to create either a number of views for subqueries and join those, or use subqueries inside the main query and simply use that.
The SQL will of course get rather long, but may be easier to read.